# How to add a new kernel version in Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

In my Yocto version (dunfell) there is a recipe for kernel 5.4 in `poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux`  directory. I need to upgrade kernel to at least 5.6. I added a recipe for this version to `meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_5.6.bb` The content of the recipe is the same as here https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-arm/tree/meta-arm-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_5.6.bb?h=master. The problem is that kernel is still building in version 5.4, not in version 5.6. I've tried to add the following line to my machine conf file:
`PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-at91 = "5.6.19"`
When I'm trying to rebuild kernel using `MACHINE=my_machine bitbake linux-at91` I'm getting the following notes:

```
NOTE: preferred version 5.6.19 of linux-at91 not available (for item linux-at91)
NOTE: versions of linux-at91 available: 4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2 4.19+gitAUTOINC+046113c438 5.4+gitAUTOINC+67771e4768
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
NOTE: preferred version 5.6.19 of linux-at91 not available (for item kernel-base)
NOTE: versions of linux-at91 available: 4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2 4.19+gitAUTOINC+046113c438 5.4+gitAUTOINC+67771e4768
NOTE: preferred version 5.6.19 of linux-at91 not available (for item kernel-image-zimage)
NOTE: versions of linux-at91 available: 4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2 4.19+gitAUTOINC+046113c438 5.4+gitAUTOINC+67771e4768
NOTE: preferred version 5.6.19 of linux-at91 not available (for item virtual/kernel)
NOTE: versions of linux-at91 available: 4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2 4.19+gitAUTOINC+046113c438 5.4+gitAUTOINC+67771e4768
```

What else can I do to upgrade kernel?

Answer (score 2):

The package version is `PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"`. Use regexp instead, e.g.

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-at91 = "5.6%"
```